# How to group bars in a barchart in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following bar chart with 4 bars:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime


co2_prices = [100, 60]
electricity_prices = [-2.6, 157]
co2_timestamps = ["March 2023", "February 2024"]
electricity_timestamps = ["24.09.2023 14:00", "24.09.2023 19:00"]


co2_timestamps = [datetime.strptime(date, "%B %Y") for date in co2_timestamps]
electricity_timestamps = [datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M") for date in electricity_timestamps]


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))  

bar_width = 0.35


co2_positions = range(len(co2_prices))
electricity_positions = [pos + 2 for pos in co2_positions]


co2_bars = ax.bar(co2_positions, co2_prices, bar_width, label='CO2 Prices (€/T)')


electricity_bars = ax.bar(electricity_positions, electricity_prices, bar_width, label='Electricity Prices (€/MWh)')
ax.set_ylim([-20, 170])

def add_values(bars):
    for bar in bars:
        yval = bar.get_height()
        plt.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2, yval + 3, round(yval, 2), ha='center', va='bottom', size='14')

add_values(co2_bars)
add_values(electricity_bars)

all_positions = list(co2_positions) + list(electricity_positions)
all_labels = ["March 2023", "February 2024", "24.09.2023 2pm", "24.09.2023 7pm"]

ax.set_xticks(all_positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(all_labels, rotation=45, ha="right" , size='14')


ax.set_xlabel('')


ax.set_ylabel('Prices', size='14')  # Adjust font weight



ax.legend(fontsize ='14')


ax.axhline(y=0, color='black', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)


ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=12)


plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('C:/Users/wi9632/Desktop/co2_price.png', dpi=300)


plt.show()
```

I have two bars for the `co2_prices = [100, 60]` with the corresponding timestamps `co2_timestamps = ["March 2023", "February 2024"]` and two bar for `electricity_prices = [-2.6, 157]` with the corrsponding timestamps `electricity_timestamps = ["24.09.2023 14:00", "24.09.2023 19:00"]`. What I want is the bars for the co2- prices should be closer to each other (lilke a cluster) and also the bars for the electricity price should be closer to each other (but farer away from the other cluster)

Comment: You are setting the positions explicitly in your script, so you could just make one small change: `co2_positions = [0, 0.5]`